# Singleton in use in authentication

Tags: c#, singleton

I came across a Singleton implementation in a site I was tasked to make changes to. The only thing I know about Singleton is its definition and as such never had an opportunity to work "with" it. So I started to read articles and this one on [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) nicely explains it. Except that the code I have looks not quite the same. Can some take a look at this and points out what this code does or how is it different?

```
public class Singleton<TSingleton> where TSingleton : class, new()
{
    private static readonly Lazy<TSingleton> instance = new Lazy<TSingleton>(() => new TSingleton());

    public static TSingleton Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }
}
```

This class is called like this `Singleton<AccessLogger>.Instance.LogAccess(accessData);` where `accessData` is an instance of AccessLoggerData and basically contains environment, page and user information. The accessData is an instance of AccessLoggerData class:

```
public class AccessLoggerData
{
    public string Environment = Singleton<ApplicationSettings>.Instance.Environment;
    public string Page, UserId;

    public AccessLoggerData(string page, string user)
    {
        this.Page = page;
        this.UserId = user;
    }
}
```

Strangely as I'm writing this post and somehow it is becoming more clear as to how these pieces come together, but one thing remains unclear, why would it be necessary to allow only one instance of this accessData object?

Answer (score 1):

*"why would it be necessary to allow only one instance of this accessData object?"*

It's a little hard to say exactly just based on the code provided. Perhaps multiple users are active on the system at the same time. The class name `AccessLoggerData` suggests that info is being logged.

You'd only want one instance logging that data if it involves file access. You wouldn't want multiple instances competing for a file write lock. The problem with this is there's nothing to suggest that in the actual code. Maybe it's meant to allow one user at a time and their state is held by this Singleton. In that case, it's bad design. Considering there's another Singleton within `AccessLoggerData` for application settings, you have a Singleton as a global: not good. It may be Singletonitis by the former developer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a generic implementation of the singleton pattern using the (newish) Lazy keyword. In its default form it make sure that only a single instance of the object created is accessed (LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication). This is important as the initialization code of the object being created might have some side effects that would be undesirable if executed twice. Checkout http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx for some more information on this.